# Как задать стиль после того, как будет проскроллена страница

Tags: jquery, javascript

Сейчас элемент находится, допустим, в 200px от топа. Как сделать так, чтобы после того, как будет проскроллено вниз 210px, то элементу будут заданы определенные стили?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ( $(this).scrollTop() >= 410 ) { 
    $('#myBlock').css( ... )
  }
});
```

Comment: на заметку: подобные функции рекомендуется оборачивать таким образом, чтобы её вызов не происходил слишком часто, наподобие [_.throttle](http://underscorejs.ru/docs/underscore.html#section-56)

Comment: Естественно, что все должно быть в разумных пределах и трактоваться поставленными задачами. К примеру, в данной задаче я бы не стал использовать _.throttle. Достаточно завести флаг установки нужных стилей и проверять при прокрутке документа высоту и установлен ли класс ( так что бы if() срабатывал только 1 раз для промежутка заданного ). Так как _.throttle будет делать подобную задачу и возможно большей кровью (использовать точно так же флаги + setTimeout )

Comment: полностью солидарен, просто не мог найти более понятный пример объясняющий суть мысли